# Algunas teclas no funcionan en el evento keyup en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo a desarollar juegos en javascript, y la verdad al manejar los eventos del teclado estoy teniendo problemas.

este es mi codigo

```
const onKeyDown = (e) => {
  let key = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.witch
  if ( board.keyCode[key] ) { //
    binaryKey = board.keyCode[key] | binaryKey
  }
}

const onKeyUp = (e) => {
  let key = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.witch
  if ( binaryKey & board.keyCode[key] ) {
    binaryKey -= board.keyCode[key]
  }
}

const start = () => {
  keyElement.innerHTML = binaryKey
  window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
  window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)
  requestAnimationFrame( main )
}

start()
```

pues, segun en del debugger todas las teclas pasan por el por el keydown, particularmente estoy utilizando las teclas de las flechas.

resulta que en el keyup no se ejecta al soltar las flechas...
de hecho, presiono teclas como la Q, W, E, R y si funciona, pero tambien presiono teclas como la A y la S y no funciona...

Curiosamente, presiono 2 teclas a la vez (ejemplo fecha arriba y flecha abajo) y hago keyup y se ejecuta una de las 2 teclas, a pesar de que si las presiono individualmente no funcionan...

Les ha pasado? o tiene por lo menos alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola, esto sucede porque depende del navegador e.keyCode funciona o no, en Mozilla Firefox creo que no funciona, hace un tiempo me ocurrió lo mismo. Puede ver mas info en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250534/event-keycode-alternative

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar el código completo? Sospecho que no es un problema de la API. La respuesta de Juanjoo Tocino no sé si será la correcta, después de todo ese error se producía con versiones de Firefox anteriores a la 38 (vamos por la 61). ¿Puedes probar este ejemplo? http://jsfiddle.net/2tu4f6sz/1/ ¿Al introducir las teclas se escriben los codes por la consola?

Comment: resolvi el problema! no era don "window", era con "document".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto mi problema.
Estaba usando `window` en lugar de `document`